# How to get information from 2 tables at once in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
<?php 

include('includes/config.php');
$topi = $_GET['id']; //id of url

mysql_select_db("ban", $con);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `basic` WHERE id = '$topi' LIMIT 0, 30"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

$aa = $row['item'];
$cc = $row['moreinfo'];
$dd = $row['contactinfo'];
$ff = $row['id'];
```

In this script, I get information from the table `basic`, but I want to retrieve data from another table named `users`. How can I retrieve data from two tables at once?

`users` table consists of following columns:

- email
- username
- ID

Comment: Please post the structure of your `users` table. What columns does it have?

Comment: @michael email,username and ID are columns

Comment: @Chamara Denipitiya Is the `ID` column related to `basic.id`?

Comment: @Chamara Denipitiya Ok I've added an example to my answer below.

Comment: The indentation in this code seems so random, I assume it must be hiding some kind of a secret message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the two tables on a common value, called a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).  Once you've posted the structure of the `users` table as requested in the comments, I can provide a more complete example.

**EDIT**: See example.  This calls explicit column names instead of `SELECT *`.

```
$query = "SELECT 
    basic.id,
    basic.item,
    basic.moreinfo,
    basic.contactinfo,
    users.email,
    users.username
  FROM basic JOIN users ON basic.id = users.id
  WHERE id   = '$topi'
  LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use a JOIN onto the other table.

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM basic b
JOIN users u ON b.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE id = '$topi'
LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Something like that, but based on your fields.

Please Note: the ON clause specifies what you will be looking for a match on.